# Best Match Search Json File

Tags: python, json, search

I have a json file with something like this:

```
{
"Cars": [
 {
  "name": 'Honda'
  "color": 'Black'
  "age": 'Old'
  },
 {
  "name": 'Ford'
  "color": ' Red'
  "age": 'Old'
  },
 {
  "name": 'Mazda'
  "color": 'Black'
  "age": 'New'
  }
 ]
}
```

I want to write a function that will prompt the user to provide a name, color, and age, and then it will search through the json and return the objects that best match the search parameters. I also want the user to be able to only enter some of the parameters.

Examples:

- User enters {'name':'Honda', 'color':None, 'age':None}, returns all the information for the Honda
- User enters {'name':None, 'color':'Black', 'age':None}, returns all the information for the Honda and the Mazda
- User enters {'name':None, 'color':'Black, 'age':'New'}, returns all of the information for the Mazda

I can't think of any programmatic ways to do this that aren't incredibly inefficient. The best thing I can think of is basically searching the whole Json for match's to the first key, then searching those for matches of the second key, then searching those for matches of the third key, then printing the resultant. Skipping keys that dont exist in the query payload would help, but that still seems really inefficient.

I'm not sure if I'm allowed to ask technique questions on here, so if the answer is that I should go build said inefficient function and then come back for info on how to improve it, that's fine, but I thought I might as well ask if there were any common examples first.

Comment: Well, if you want to find the "best match"... can you think of a rule that tells you "how good" a match is?

Comment: I dont want to find the 'best' match, I want the 'best' way to find 'all' match's. To put it more basically, I want the user to be able to enter 1-3 parameters, and get every json object that has at least those parameters. You asking me that question is basically why I'm here. I couldn't seem to google/stack search the correct words to get the sorts of solutions I'm looking for. I know this is not new ground, I'm just having trouble uncovering the common methodologies.

Comment: You're basically asking us to design a data base application and teach you how to code it.  This is far too broad for Stack Overflow.  You're asking for a search capability with wild cards or simply unrestricted parameters.  You need to research existing data base packages, or perhaps merely learn the PANDAS data frame interface.

Comment: I guess creating a Pandas database is probably easier than trying to search a JSON file. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 2):

```
#lets say your json is stored in variable json_var
car_name=input("car name")
car_color=input("car color")
car_age=input("car_age")

car_list=[]
for cars in json_var["cars"]:
    if (cars["name"]==car_name or cars["color"]==car_color or cars["age"]==car_age):
        car_list.append(cars["name"])

print(car_list)
```